# Selecting data between timestamp range when timestamp is string in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Document structure looks like following in MongoDB. Timestamp is stored as string in mongo so ISODate doesn't work. How can I select the data between two timestamps in this case.

```
    {
     "_id" : NumberLong(5702509046), 
    "totalProduct" : "0.00", 
    "status" : "COMPLETED", 
    "dateCreated" : "10/02/2020 11:31:48", 
    "lastUpdated" : "10/13/2020 15:39:18"
}
```

Among the several other things, I tried something like this to convert the string date into date object and then do the comparison but this doesn't take end timestamp into consideration. It returns all documents greater than the input date but doesn't stop at the end date. Need help with straightening this query

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection").find({"$expr": {"$gte": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$lastUpdated" ,timezone:"America/New_York"}}, new Date("10/09/2020 10:40:55") ]},"$expr": {"$lte": [{ "$dateFromString": { "dateString":"$lastUpdated",timezone:"America/New_York"}}, new Date("10/12/202010:14:55") ]},status:{$in:["COMPLETED"]}},{"_id":1, "lastUpdated":1}).sort({"lastUpdated":-1});
```

Comment: You can try using one `$expr` within which you specify the condition (includes both greater-than and less-than).

Comment: It looks like expr can have only one field. "Query failed with error code 15983 and error message 'An object representing an expression must have exactly one field:"

Comment: use it with the `$and` operator, something like this: `$expr: { $and: [  { $gte: [ { $toDate: "$date1" }, START_DT  ] }, { $lte: [ { $toDate: "$date2" }, END_DT  ] } ] }`

Comment: Yes, that seems to have worked.  Thank you for your help @prasad_